# Text box not showing all elements on first line

Tags: c#

Get complete string in Index and all its elements with `string[,]`

I have no errors. I want to display:

```
  A0003
Dog on Wheels
0
Yes
A0012
Cart with Blocks(50)
0
Yes
```

```
for (Index = 0; Index < 39; Index++) {
    for (Element = 0; Element < 3; Element++) {
        // public static bool TryParse(ProductListings[Index, Element] , out Int32 result);
        if (int.TryParse(ProductListings[Index, Element], out NoStock)) {
            if (NoStock == 0)
                for (Element = 0; Element < 4; Element++) {
                    Stock.Text += ProductListings[Index, Element] + Environment.NewLine;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Like this:

```
A0003 Dog on Wheels 0 Yes
A0012 Cart with Blocks(50) 0 Yes
```

Comment: Is it a homework? What is the input and the context  of the issue?

Comment: Yes it is a homework question. The content of the issue is that I want to display the index and the elements within index on one line. The next index and element on the next line.

Comment: I tried to copy & paste a screenshot of the problem...dosen't appear to have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this as well. It kind of works.

```
      public void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel.Clear();
        Panel.GridLines = true;
        Panel.Columns.Add("Item Code");
        Panel.Columns.Add("Product Item Description");
        Panel.Columns.Add("Count");
        Panel.Columns.Add("On Order");
        Panel.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
        Panel.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);

        string[,] ProductListings =
        {
         {"A0001","Horse on Wheels","5","No"},
         {"A0002","Elephant on Wheels","2","No"},
         {"A0003","Dog on Wheels","0","Yes"},
         {"A0004","Seal on Wheels","3","No"},
         {"A0005","Bear on Wheels","7","No"},
         {"A0006","Teddy Bear","2","Yes"},
         {"A0007","Clown","5","No"},
         {"A0008","Puppy(crouch)","3","No"},
         {"A0009","Puppy(stand)","2","No"},
         {"A0010","Puppy(jump)","2","Yes"},
         {"A0011","Puppy(lying)","1","Yes"},
         {"A0012","Cart with Blocks(50)","0","Yes"},
         {"A0013","Cart with Blocks(100)","5","No"},
         {"A0014","Cart with Blocks(200)","4","No"},
         {"A0015","Train with 0 Carriage","12","No"},
         {"A0016","Train with 1 Carriage","10","No"},
         {"A0017","Train with 2 Carriage","5","Yes"},
         {"A0018","Train with 3 Carriage","4","Yes"},
         {"A0019","Train with 4 Carriage","5","No"},
         {"A0020","Train with 5 Carriage","2","No"},
         {"A0021","Building Blocks(20)","15","No"},
         {"A0022","Building Blocks(30)","13","No"},
         {"A0023","Building Blocks(40)","16","No"},
         {"A0024","Building Blocks(50)","5","Yes"},
         {"A0025","Building Blocks(100)","2","Yes"},
         {"A0026","Building Blocks(200)","8","No"},
         {"A0027","Windmill","5","No"},
         {"A0028","Farmhouse","6","Yes"},
         {"A0029","Fencing","22","Yes"},
         {"A0030","Barn","12","Yes"},
         {"A0031","Tractor","6","Yes"},
         {"A0032","Animals","3","Yes"},
         {"A0033","House","9","No"},
         {"A0034","Car","12","No"},
         {"A0035","Building(small)","4","No"},
         {"A0036","Building(medium)","3","No"},
         {"A0037","Building(tall)","4","No"},
         {"A0038","Shop","7","No"},
         {"A0039","Traffic Lights","5","Yes"},
         {"A0040","Petrol Station","4","Yes"}
        };

        for (int Index = 0; Index < 39; Index++)
           {
            Panel.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[]{ProductListings[Index,0],ProductListings[Index,1],ProductListings[Index,2],ProductListings[Index,3]}));
           }

    }
```